# Better Realtime filter/search option to integrate in ASP.NET MVC application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, search, typeahead

Our SQL Server database has a huge number of data in different tables (millions of records) and we are populating the data using paging in the UI. Data is dynamically added and updated. Now I am planning to implement realtime filtering/searching of the data. The UI will have a text box where user types search keyword and the rows in the grid should be refreshed based on the search string as a typeahead functionality. I am thinking to use azure search as one of the candidate for implementing this functionality. But we are not on cloud yet and I have to justify my team if we had to go through this route.

Are there any other products or methods that can help in achieving this? I am still doing research on this. But if anyone has already implemented a solution like this, I would like to know more about your recommendations.

Answer (score 0):

I recently started using https://datatables.net, and it's been a good experience.

Otherwise, you'll probably have to roll your own solution that keeps track of page and filter criteria on the client side and makes Ajax calls whenever they're altered.  Your endpoint would need to take the page and filter as parameters, perform the necessary query of the data, and return the desired records.